# Как указать роут контроллера в js файле

Tags: laravel

Здравствуйте я написал Js в шаблоне blade и указал в нем Url на метод котроллера, но перенеся логику js в отдельный файл Url перестал работать. Можете подсказать в чем дело и как поставить правильно Url в Js файле?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contact").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('contact')}}",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#load").fadeIn(400);
            },
            type: "post",
            data: $("#contact").serialize(),
            success: function (answer) {
                $("#answer").html(answer);
            }
        }).done(function () {
            $("#load").fadeOut(400);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не будет работать, поскольку js файлы не проходят через php компилятор и отдаются в том виде, в котором были написаны.

Есть 2 пути:

- Использовать библиотеку https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer. Для простых проектов довольно хороший выбор.
- Сделать файл конфига в js, который будет добавлять в глобальный скоуп js'a те переменные, которые вам будут нужны и поставить на какую-нибудь artisan команду. В одном из моих проектов такое было, просто писал `php artisan make:js` и он генерировал `variables.js` файл.

Comment: То есть если я просто url поменяю правильно не поможет?

Comment: @Vladimir т.е. может помочь неправильно? это как?

Comment: То есть если я просто url поменяю на правильный не поможет?